# Facebook user login time and session

Tags: facebook, session, authentication

is there a way to check user's login time and the duration of that session? I want my app to check what time the user logged in and for how long

Answer (score 1):

Nope, FB API doesn't provide such information.

Comment: @user1472707: I don't know any